# Elasticsearch startup: not available immediately

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a Docker image which contains and starts Elasticsearch (as well as MySQL, etc.).

The problem is that while `services elasticsearch start` works and succeeds in roughly 1s (when the container starts), the service isn't available immediately.

When we try to `wget` the status page immediately after, we get a connection error (Elasticsearch is off). If we do `sleep 10` then Elasticsearch will be available…

This is very confusing:

- why isn't Elasticsearch up immediately after `services elasticsearch start`?
- what can we do (except `sleep 10`)? what's the proper way to handle that?

Note: there is no data, this is an empty container/elasticsearch. There's only 1 shard.

Comment: Just simply cause the service needs time to start and also if the cluster contains lots of shards, it might take time to recover them.

Comment: @eliasah There's only 1 shard, and no data. It's a freshly built Docker container.

Comment: That's why I said if. Thus its first the first reason I gave you.

Comment: @eliasah I'm just answering your comment too…